# Trying to understand how set timer functions works in MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I m confused about set timer functions in MFC; how it works? is it a thread which waits for a defined period of time or something else? please some one explain it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a thin wrapper on the Windows function call https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx  It will post a message (WM_TIMER) to your message queue no earlier than the time requested and only when the message queue is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetTimer asks the operating system to generate a WM_TIMER message at the specified interval. So the timing is done within the operating system's multitasking, not within the calling app.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a special thread. Every Win32 thread of a process can have message queue if the process posses a window. Console application threads get one with the first call of a "user32.dll" function. A message/event driven Application like a MFC application use that message queue. SetTimer is identical to the Win32 pedant SetTimer. It directs the OS (yes, not your application) to emit a WM_TIMER message in a given interval to your application. The main message loop of your application dispatch that to your MFC Class. If you set a CALLBACK, the default windowproc will call that CALLBACK instead of dispatching the WM_TIMER message.
If you block your main loop (e.g. by Sleep(10000)) no WM_TIMER message will be dispatched.
Timer messages do never come to an exact interval. If you want a signal every 1000 millisecond, you can get one after 1100 or at 900. 
The roots of WM_TIMER goes back to the ancient time where MS used cooperative multitasking as wording for there one process OS Windows.

Comment: *"Every Win32 application has a message queue"* - Uhm, no. Unless a thread calls one of the USER32 functions, no queue is created. This is generally the case for applications running in the CONSOLE subsystem, for example.

Comment: @IInspectable I was imprecise and partly wrong. I corrected that with your suggestion, thx.

Comment: This is still inaccurate: Message queues are owned by threads, not applications.

Comment: @IInspectable Thats what I have learned too. But cannot only one thread of a process have a message queue? I never saw a "two queue" process. Isn't better for understanding to only speak of one queue per process even if it's not perfect accurate?

Comment: Every thread owned by a process can have a message or input queue. A common scenario for multiple queues is, when you host a COM server in its own thread. You may not be aware of this if you use a library (like ATL). Accurate description of ownership is vital in understanding, why multi-threaded GUIs are challenging, for example.

Comment: @IInspectable I wasn't aware of that! Especially in the COM case. In my opinion in an apartment thread situation all calls where queued by the main threads queue, in a multithread apartment the calls were direct. Maybe you got a link to a deeper explanation. I changed my answer to reflect your notice.

Comment: A process can have any number of STAs. COM dispatches and synchronizes calls to objects in an STA using window messages. As a consequence, each STA thread must retrieve and dispatch messages. This implies that every STA thread has a message queue. Detailed information: [Descriptions and Workings of OLE Threading Models](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/150777).